# Derivative of integral and variable substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

My question is about the validity of this identity and if there is some error in my argument:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}f(t-x)dx = -\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(t-x)dx$$

The argument goes as follows. If I do the substitution $u=t-x$ then,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{\infty}f(t-x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}f(t-x)dx = -\int_t^{-\infty} \frac{d}{dt}f(u)du.$$

Also,

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(u)=\frac{df(u)}{du}\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{df(u)}{du}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(u)=\frac{df(u)}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{df(u)}{du}$$

so,

$$...= -\int_t^{-\infty}\frac{d}{dt}f(u)du=\int_t^{-\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(u)du=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(t-x)dx$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't interchange $\frac{d}{dt}$ with $\int_0^\infty$ in general.

However, by chain rule you have 
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t-x) = f'(t-x) = -\frac{d}{dx} f(t-x).$$ 
You don't need substitution for that.

Comment: Yes, the chain rule identity was in my question. But what conditions must be met in order to interchange the derivative with the integral? Or how can I do it in this particular case?

Comment: @layn: It depends on the integral (Lebesgue?) and on $f$. You need something like $|f'(t-x)| \le g(x)$ for any $t$ and $\int_0^\infty g < \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand why your answer got a downvote...